# Can someone help me identify this vintage two pin diode circled in red?

Tags: diodes, identification

Can someone help me identify this two pin diode circled in red, or a possible generic replacement?

This board came out of a light-duty pin nailer, it's vintage. There were two diodes right next to each other and I removed one and could barely make out the letters on the remaining diode:

N4D

Not sure If these are 100% correct.

[image]

Comment: 3 of the 20 pixel let me guess it is a 1N4007

Comment: @Jens You never got one of these computers from the movies, with infinite zoom?

Comment: Are the diodes really bad?  How did you test them?

Comment: 1999 is "vintage" now?  I suddenly feel really old.

Comment: Please consider rewording your title. As asked, the answer to your question is simply "maybe."

Answer (score 1):

The package is a DO-41. Diodes like the 1N4001 - 1N4007 have their name printed on them, you could easily misread the 0 as a D.
I suggest you remove it and try to read the full name.

If removal of the second diode is not an option or the name is not readable 1N4001 - 1N4007 differ mostly in the maximum reverse voltage.

- 1N4001: 50V
- 1N4002: 100V
- 1N4003: 200V
- 1N4004: 400V
- 1N4005: 600V
- 1N4006: 800V
- 1N4007: 1000V

If you are unsure pick the 1N4007, this should be fine for your application.

General note: Normally diodes don't burn up by themselves, check your circuit for other failures!

Comment: Copy that, Hans mitm Flammenwerfer